# Reading JSON data with axios and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I created this backend json response.

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.3714624,
                "lng": 21.7614661
            },
            "_id": "5f9bb2ff4fc07350c317500c",
            "title": "Alcazar Park",
            "description": "A lovely park.",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg",
            "creator": "5f9bb2ee4fc07350c317500b",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5f9bb2ff4fc07350c317500c"
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.3714624,
                "lng": 21.7614661
            },
            "_id": "5f9bb4f9d92cd5541f5922fc",
            "title": "Alcazar Park",
            "description": "A beautiful park.",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg",
            "creator": "5f9bb2ee4fc07350c317500b",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5f9bb4f9d92cd5541f5922fc"
        },
        {
            "location": {
                "lat": 40.3714624,
                "lng": 21.7614661
            },
            "_id": "5f9bb632d92cd5541f5922fd",
            "title": "Train station of Larisa",
            "description": "An old but cool train station",
            "image": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/10/Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg/400px-Empire_State_Building_%28aerial_view%29.jpg",
            "creator": "5f9bb2ee4fc07350c317500b",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "5f9bb632d92cd5541f5922fd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to display in a list just the title of each place in the array. Here is my code
for that in React

```
const DataFetching = () => {
    const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get('http://localhost:5000/api/places/user/5f9bb2ee4fc07350c317500b')
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res)
            setPosts(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }, []);

    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
                {
                    posts.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li>)
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataFetching;
```

However, I am getting this error

How can I fix it?

```
TypeError: posts.map is not a function
```

Thanks,
Theo

Comment: `setPosts(res.data.places)`

Comment: Check if `res.data` is an array or not, error message suggests that its not.

Comment: return <></> if posts is not an array. Maybe no data is being fetched from the API and posts is undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
setPosts(res.data.places)


posts?.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}
```

or:

```
setPosts(res.data)


posts.places?.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}
```

Comment: Optional-chaining will not prevent the error because OP is incorrectly setting the state to an object instead of an array. Optional-chaining will only help if `posts` is undefined.

Comment: What's about this: setPosts(res.data.places)?

Comment: Yes that is the correct way to update the state in this case. You don't need optional-chaining here because initial value of `places` is an empty array. Would be nice if you add an explanation of what OP did wrong and why your answer will work.

Comment: True think the better way is: setPosts(res.data) adn use it in render: posts.places?.map(post => <li key={post.id}>{post.title}